# linker error after compiling

Tags: c++, c, opengl, sdl

Im having a problem with the linker i guess

This is what i get on the output tab:

```
1>main-light.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_FreeSurface referenced in function "private: unsigned int __thiscall objloader::loadTexture(char const *)" (?loadTexture@objloader@@AAEIPBD@Z)
1>main-light.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_LoadBMP_RW referenced in function "private: unsigned int __thiscall objloader::loadTexture(char const *)" (?loadTexture@objloader@@AAEIPBD@Z)
1>main-light.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_RWFromFile referenced in function "private: unsigned int __thiscall objloader::loadTexture(char const *)" (?loadTexture@objloader@@AAEIPBD@Z)
1>main-light.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_GetTicks referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Player::init(void)" (?init@Player@@QAEXXZ)
1>main-light.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_GetKeyState referenced in function "void __cdecl Control(float,float,bool)" (?Control@@YAXMM_N@Z)
1>main-light.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_WarpMouse referenced in function "void __cdecl Control(float,float,bool)" (?Control@@YAXMM_N@Z)
1>main-light.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_GetMouseState referenced in function "void __cdecl Control(float,float,bool)" (?Control@@YAXMM_N@Z)
1>main-light.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_ShowCursor referenced in function "void __cdecl Control(float,float,bool)" (?Control@@YAXMM_N@Z)
1>main-light.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_Delay referenced in function _SDL_main
1>main-light.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_GL_SwapBuffers referenced in function _SDL_main
1>main-light.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_PollEvent referenced in function _SDL_main
1>main-light.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_SetVideoMode referenced in function _SDL_main
1>main-light.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_Init referenced in function _SDL_main
1>MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
1>C:\Users\Tiago\Desktop\Projects\FPS\Debug\FPS.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 14 unresolved externals
```

here is the command line of the linker (if it can help you...):

```
/OUT:"C:\Users\Tiago\Desktop\Projects\FPS\Debug\FPS.exe" /NOLOGO "SDL.lib" "SDLmain.lib" "glu32.lib" "glut32.lib" "opengl32.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /MANIFEST /ManifestFile:"Debug\FPS.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ALLOWISOLATION /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"C:\Users\Tiago\Desktop\Projects\FPS\Debug\FPS.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /PGD:"C:\Users\Tiago\Desktop\Projects\FPS\Debug\FPS.pgd" /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE
```

More information:
i've put the OpenGL and SDL folder (the folder with the include and lib files) in the main folder of my project. Is it causing the problem?

Comment: You should just link to their libs directory, there is no reason to copy them into your program's folder.  Are you sure that you have configured your project to link all required libraries?

Comment: You are getting unresolved symbols rather than the linker complaining about not finding libraries.  That usually means you haven't included the correct libraries on the command line rather than you didn't have the libraries in a good place.

Comment: where should i place the lib files?

Comment: You need to tell the linker to look for them. Read your system's documentation.

Comment: You are missing a few things. 1. You need to tell the linker the path of the libs. 2. You need to list SDLmain.lib BEFORE SDL.lib. This has to do with linker interposing (I assume). If you still get an unresolved external symbol for SDL_main, write #undef main above your main function. That works because SDL redefines main to be SDL_main. It does this so SDL's main will be called first and it can do some initialization for you.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find anything relevant in the SDL docs on how to configure your project properly.  The header files gives some hints, it uses non-standard #defines to select the platform.  Which explains the first set of linker errors, the DECLSPEC macro has to be set correctly.  For some *really* mysterious reason it wants to rename main() as well, the reason for your last linker error.  No clue why any of this is necessary, these kind of hacks tend to be used as a filter.  As in, "can't figure this out by yourself, don't bug us with your other questions".

First thing you have to do: right-click your project, Properties, Linker, Advanced, Entry Point = SDL_main.  Make your code look similar to this, I hard-coded the paths and told the linker what to link:

```
include "stdafx.h"
#define __WIN32__    // Non-standard define to select the platform
#include "c:/temp/sdl-1.2.15/include/sdl.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "c:/temp/sdl-1.2.15/lib/x86/sdl.lib")


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);   // Just an example
    // etc...
    return 0;
}
```

It linked correctly, that's all I tried.  Running it requires sdl.dll in the same directory as your .exe.  Good luck with it, sounds like you'll need it.